# How safe is using var t=!0 / var t=!1 for true / false? Do they always return true boolean true / false?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

Many of us have seen / use the following:

```
var t=!0; (t will equal true)
var t=!1; (t will equal false)
```

How safe is this method of evaluating true / false?

I see google use this all the time.

Will these ALWAYS return a **boolean** true / false?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

> 11.4.9 Logical NOT Operator ( ! )
>
> The production UnaryExpression : ! UnaryExpression is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Let oldValue be ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)).
> 3. If oldValue is true, return false.
> 4. Return true.

Source: http://es5.github.com/x11.html#x11.4.9

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they'll always return `true` and `false`.

More specifically, `!x` will return `true` for *any* "falsey" value (`undefined`, `""`, etc) and conversely return `false` for *any* "truthy" value.

A more common idiom is `!!x` which converts any "falsey" value to strictly `false` and any "truthy" value to strictly `true` - in other words it's like a "type cast" to a boolean.